# ngRepeat Filter by Array name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following JSON structure in my Angular app:

[image: JSON Structure]

Sample: http://pastie.org/pastes/9476207/text?key=u6mobe15chwyiz1jakn0w

And the following HTML which is displaying every product in the parent array:

```
<div class="bb-product-grid" ng-repeat="brand in notebooks">
    <ul ng-repeat="products in brand">
        <li ng-repeat="Notebook in products">
            <span class="product-title">{{Notebook.Model}}</span>
            <span class="product-description"><p>{{Notebook.Description}}</p></span>
            <span class="product-image">image</span>
            <span class="product-add-to-bundle"><button>Add to bundle</button></span>
            <span class="product-price">{{Notebook.Price}}<sub>pcm</sub></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to be able to filter the products by the brand names (array names, Acer, Apple etc.).

By default, only the 'Apple' products will be visible. You will then click a button to change the visible results to reflect what brand you've selected. So if you then select HP, you'll only see 'HP' products.

I'm a little stuck on this because the JSON structure is pretty nested, if it was 1/2 levels I'd be able to cope but I can't figure this out, I seem to only show all the products or break the app. Any advice on the best-practise approach to this (I'm guessing I might have to create a custom filter?) will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give us an example of the JSON itself?

Comment: @ExplosionPills modified post with link

Comment: Who is creating this JSON?  You should probably change it if you can -- `Notebooks` doesn't need to be an array right now (it's an array of one object) but you could change it to be an array of objects with filterable properties.

Comment: I've created the JSON, there will be other properties being added later such as smartphones and tablets which will be new arrays

Comment: They don't need to be arrays if they're only one element OR they can be arrays with multiple elements.  I can show you what I mean if you don't understand

Comment: Yah sure, that would help!

Comment: Does [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fa7KBw1f0R3CCH4RL4a4?p=preview) do what you need?

Comment: @mobabur94 that does exactly what I need, the JSON format is a lot cleaner too. If you post your solution as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @leaksterrr, okay cool

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your data to be in this format:

```
$scope.data = [
  {
    brand: 'Acer',
    laptops: ['acer_1', 'acer_2', 'acer_3', 'acer_4', 'acer_5']
  },
  {
    brand: 'Apple',
    laptops: ['apple_1', 'apple_2', 'apple_3', 'apple_4', 'apple_5']
  },
  {
    brand: 'Asus',
    laptops: ['asus_1', 'asus_2', 'asus_3', 'asus_4', 'asus_5']
  },
  {
    brand: 'HP',
    laptops: ['hp_1', 'hp_2', 'hp_3', 'hp_4', 'hp_5']
  },
  {
    brand: 'Lenovo',
    laptops: ['lenovo_1', 'lenovo_2', 'lenovo_3', 'lenovo_4', 'lenovo_5']
  },
  {
    brand: 'Toshiba',
    laptops: ['toshiba_1', 'toshiba_2', 'toshiba_3', 'toshiba_4', 'toshiba_5']
  }
];
```

Then you can use have a filter like so:

```
$scope.search = {
  brand: 'HP'
};
```

With HTML:

```
<select ng-model="search.brand">
  <option ng-repeat="company in data">{{company.brand}}</option>
</select>
<ul ng-repeat="company in data | filter:search">
  <li><b ng-bind="company.brand"></b></li>
  <ul ng-repeat="laptop in company.laptops">
    <li ng-bind="laptop"></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fa7KBw1f0R3CCH4RL4a4?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

`brands` is an array of objects with the brand names as keys.  It doesn't make sense to use filters to solve this problem ... however it's easy to get the products if you have the key name.  Imagine you have `searchName = 'Apple'` and `obj = [{Apple: []}, {Acer: []}]`.  You could just use `obj[0].Apple`.

```
this.filterItem = "Apple";
this.productsToShow = productObject[0][this.filterItem];

<select ng-model=ctrl.filterItem><!-- brand names go here --></select>
<ul ng-repeat="product in ctrl.productsToShow">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use filter, when only ever one is supposed to be visisble. Instead, skip the iteration over the brands, and instead just iterate over the *selected brand*. All you need to do is then make sure you set `selectedBrand` to the correct subset of your data structure.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wwboysu/2/

```
Show brand:
<span ng-repeat="(name,brand) in notebooks.Notebooks[0]" ng-click="selected(brand)">
   {{name}} -  <br>
</span>

<ul ng-repeat="products in selectedBrand">
    <!-- snip -->
</ul>

$scope.selected = function(brand) {
      $scope.selectedBrand = brand;  
};
```

However, if you have control over the JSON, I'd try to return it in a format better suited for what you're trying to do.

Comment: The `brand in notebooks` repeat is just displaying ALL of the JSON data?

Comment: I'm getting '0' - I do prefer the first method you've posted as that's not bloating the HTML

Comment: Updated it, the problem is the layout of your notebook array. It had a key and also an array with one element everything is inside.

Comment: Now https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=products%20in%20selectedBrand&p1=string:p - I think I need to change the structure of my JSON...?

Comment: Yeah I don't get it, i'm using the same code as you and it's not working for me?

Comment: It's failing silently -.-

Comment: (name,brand) in notebooks[0]

Answer (score -1):

Add this filter which will take a brand:

```
 <ul ng-repeat="brand in notebooks| filter:filterBrand">
```

in controller

```
$scope.SelectedBrandName= "Apple";

$scope.filterBrand = function(brand){
if(brand.Name == $scope.SelectedBrandName)
    return true;

 return false;
};
```

This will look at each brand and only allow brands that return true.  If you have a button that changes the $scope.SelectedBrandName value to a different name, it will automatically filter through the ng-repeat to only brands that match.

Comment: `if(bool) { return true; } else { return false; }` is redundant

Comment: Your answer has appeared in the low quality posts queue. Please add an explanation as how your code solves the OPs question.